# Querying on custom user type or role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

EF 6, Identity 2, ASP.NET MVC 5, code first

My application uses Identity for managing users; I have the standard `ApplicationUser` with some added properties:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync ...

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```

I'm also using two roles: `admin` and `teacher`. Most users will have the `teacher` role, some will have `admin`. There might even be some cases where both roles, or neither, are applied to some given user.

I also have a `Teacher` model, as follows:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }

    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    public virtual School School { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TeacherAssignment> Assignments { get; set; }
}
```

This model is useful for connecting teachers to their respective schools, as well as to the course sections they teach. Access to teachers in the database is straightforward:

```
public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; } // teacher access
...
contextInstance.Teachers // get the current teachers
```

All well and good to this point. I can manage users and their roles, and manage teachers, both in respective views. My problem with this is the code duplication, and added overhead of maintaining a teacher in two places. Also, a Teacher might stop teaching, yet still be a user, perhaps an admin. Conversely, an existing user may need to also become a teacher.

My ideas for resolving the issue:

1) Modify the `Teacher` model to extend `ApplicationUser`, dropping the duplicate properties from `Teacher`. No duplication, straightforward access. Yet a bit redundant with the `teacher` role. Also, a user might no longer be a teacher, so the teacher record would have to be deleted; conversely, a teacher record must be created to accompany an existing user. All teachers are users, but not all users are teachers.

2) Keep `Teacher` model, but have it connected to an `ApplicationUser` instance:

```
public class Teacher {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Some overhead on managing teachers separately, and some redundancy with the corresponding role, but can easily get from a user to a matching teacher, or vise versa. Same straightforward teacher retrieval, no danger of getting back non-teachers. Not all users will have matching teacher records.

3) Drop the `Teacher` model and related data access, and retrieve users who are in the `teacher` role. This slightly complicates retrieval of the appropriate users; the teacher retrieval query shown earlier could be replaced with a call to a helper function:

```
// within a class that receives a reference to the context
public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> Teachers
{
    get
    {
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_context));

        var role = roleManager.FindByName("teacher");
        var roleId = role.Id;

        var users = Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roleId));
        return users;
    }
}
```

No duplication or added management. A user is not an active teacher? Remove user from the `teacher` role, or add a user to the role to gain another teacher. Impact on code should be minimal, changing from direct access to using the helper function.

My feeling is that option #3 is the better one, as it eliminates duplication, doesn't require separate views for managing another user type, and should be straightforward to implement. Does #3 look the ideal route, or is there any other alternative that may work better?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the `Teacher` class? Will there be any `Teacher` who is not a user?

Even if there will be, by adding this property `public virtual ICollection<TeacherAssignment> Assignments { get; set; }` to the `ApplicationUser` class you will not lose any memory. It will be translated into new table (TeacherId,AssignmentId) either way.

If later on you decide that Admin also can be assigned to something you can use it. In my opinion this one field more is not worth of new class furthermore it will complicate it in database.

Comment: I used `Teacher` because it was initially logical to do so as part of the object model. It made relationships easy to set up. As it turns out there are not many relationships around the teacher model, and it is less useful to have than I initially thought.